# Char encode in node.js ChildProcess.fork()

Tags: node.js, fork, asterisk, child-process, asteriskami

I had to move the code from app.js file inside another one and I use childProcess.fork().
Now I have to catch messages from ami-asterisk inside the child process, but I noticed that special char like "à,è,ò,.." are converted into other char like "h,l,..". Asterisk send to app the right char, but something change with the fork. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1):

Use tcpdump and see how message go via tcp.

After that use debug technics in your selected language(js) to see how it go via framework(node.js).